# How can I use a batch file to MSBuild solutions in multiple directories at once?

Tags: msbuild, batch-file

I am an intern with a start-up company. I don't know anything about Batch files, XML files, the command prompt, or msbuild. I only know the basics of C#.

I have been asked to make a batch file that allows a user to build ALL solutions in a directory, with seven subfolders, in one command. I know how to build one solution in a single folder (by using `msbuild mysolution.sln`), but to build many solutions from seven different folders is beyond me.

It is possible to make a batch file that allows msbuild to find all solution files in the subfolders and build them all at once?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Save following targets file as `buildall.targets` in the root of your solutions directory

   ```
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
            DefaultTargets="Default">

       <ItemGroup>
           <AllFiles Include=".\**\*.sln"/>
       </ItemGroup>

       <Target Name="Default">
            <MSBuild Projects="@(AllFiles)"/>
       </Target>

    </Project>
   ```
2. Create batch file named `BuildAll.cmd` with following content: (change path to msbuild.exe depends on .NET Framework version you are using)

   ```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild buildall.targets
   ```
3. Run/execute `BuildAll.cmd`

See [MSDN: How to: Select the Files to Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx) for more details on recursive folder traversal, especially "Specifying Inputs with Wildcards" part

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have done as you've said (hopefully), but I am receiving this error: `error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: Project. Line 9, position 10` Do you know what that means?

Comment: @user1015106 it means you have made a copy/paste error, by missing at least the last line (with `</Project>` in it). Make sure you copy the complete "gray box" into the file `buildall.targets`.

Comment: Thank you, Christian K. and sll. I really appreciate your help.