# How to attempt to build all project in a project group even if one fails to compile

Tags: delphi, build

We have a Jenkins task that runs overnight and compiles a project group containing all of our projects. Unfortunately this task stops on the first error in a project. This means we don't get the full list of errors in the project group and even though more than one checkin may have contained errors only one checkin will be flagged as a problem.

Is there any way to force the Delphi compiler to continue to build all projects in the project group?

Comment: If you use MSBuild, you can create a BAT file which will build each project and continue on to the next whether or not the previous one succeeded, otherwise David's solution is your best bet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should go to LaKraven who suggested this answer in a comment, but I was unable to tick it.

'If you use MSBuild, you can create a BAT file which will build each project and continue on to the next whether or not the previous one succeeded'

There is another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608927/how-can-i-use-a-batch-file-to-msbuild-solutions-in-multiple-directories-at-once) that shows more details about this.

The only change we made to get it to work was to use the following buildall.targets instead:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
     DefaultTargets="Default">

<ItemGroup>
    <AllFiles Include=".\**\*.dproj"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Default">
     <MSBuild Projects="@(AllFiles)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested. Build each individual project rather than the group project.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to build each project separately.