# Batch file to build two .net solutions with circular dependency

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, msbuild, circular-dependency

I have two solutions with multiple projects each. The two solutions utilize circular dependency to get a full build of the application.

Basically

```
1. Build two projects from solution 1.
2. Build three projects from solution 2.
3. Build all solution 1.
4. Build all solution 2.
```

Which is fine, once built it runs great, the problem is if it is updated at all by another developer I have to get latest, then go through the whole process again....and again....and again.

After some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608927/how-can-i-use-a-batch-file-to-msbuild-solutions-in-multiple-directories-at-once) question/answer which showed how to build all solutions in a directory using a batch file. My question would take this a step further, is it possible to build specific projects from multiple solutions, alternating between solutions as the build progresses using a batch file?

Thanks.

Comment: You can build a specific project with `MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:ProjectName:TargetName`

Comment: @stuartd if I were to add, say, 5 projects from multiple solutions in a list to a batch file would it try to run them concurrently or would it execute iteratively?

Comment: As long as there's one line for each, I would expect it to run each one at a time.

Comment: Hi there, a circular dependency gives me the whiff of code-smell!  I'd be careful working against the development environment by trying to bandage around this problem! Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a specific project with MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:ProjectName:TargetName

Per stuartd (from comment)